# PHP OAuth Extension "Failure when receiving data from the peer"

Tags: php, oauth

I am using the PHP OAuth extension to connect to the Netflix API and pull data through a GET request.

Running the request on my local machine results in a successful try and the correct data returned.

However, upon pushing the request up to our 'live' server, I've immediately run into issues with the PHP OAuth extension failing.

I am using version 1.2.2 of the extension with curl as my request method (libcurl is also installed).  My PHP code to call the OAuth fetch is:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($this->key, $this->secret);
$resource = $oauth->fetch($url, array('v' => '2.0', 'include_tms' => 'true'));
$this->_writeFile($oauth->getLastResponse());
```

Again, this exact code works 100% on my local dev machine (Mac running OS X Lion, installed php-oauth through MacPorts ... also version 1.2.2 ... PHP 5.3.8).  However, when running on our server (Debian Linux, PHP 5.3.3, installed php-oauth through apt-get) I receive the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'making the request failed (Failure when receiving data from the peer)' in /var/www/familymedia/application/Services/Netflix.php:23

I'm really not sure what to make of this error.

Some further info:

We currently make successful cURL requests from our server to other API services and return back good information without issue on an hourly basis.  However, none of those services authenticate through OAuth, so none of them required the OAuth extension and I ran them straight with php curl.

I have a feeling that there is some sort of setup issue with the php-oauth extension on our live server that MacPorts "magically" solved for me during install on my local machine ... but I cannot find any install or configuration advice/instruction/etc that has helped.

Hoping someone has an answer or a place to point me for further discovery toward an answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd update this question with the answer found:  the company was specifically blocking inbound communication from Netflix.  IT solved the issue.  Not a very exciting answer, but that's what it was.